# How to pass a list of Guids through an ActionLink parameter?

Tags: c#, list, parameters, html.actionlink

Basically I have a list of Guids and I want to pass this list as a parameter to a controller action.
This is what I come up with so far, but its not working.

```
var contactsParam = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var count = 0;

foreach (var selectedUserId in selectedUserIds)
{
    contactsParam.Add("selectedUserId[" + count + "]", selectedUserId);
    count++;
}

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "SomeAction", "Controller", new RouteValueDictionary(contactsParams), null)
```

Then this is the controller action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SomeAction(Guid[] selectedUserIds)
{}
```

I've tried to pass through just a basic list on its own, and also an IEnumerable, however they both send through 0 results.  I've searched online and found what I have above, but it doesn't seem to be working. 
Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Ok, Well after more research I've found that there is apparently no where of passing a complex type through an action link as a GET.  So I guess I will just have to use TempData or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've just passed them as strings and converted them on the other end. Not very elegant I know.